# Should an «interface» to my class constructor be part of my class? (How?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, constructor

I have a class with a very generic initialisator accepting any combination of `args` and `kwargs`. I would like to implement another way to build instances, which will use 3 lists: one for `args` and two for `kwargs` (`Key` and `values`, both the same length). Obviously, I cannot do that with my normal `__init()__` method, since passing 3 lists is a perfectly valid case for it.

```
class MyVeryGenericClass:
    __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass   #Do something really nice with args and kwargs, any case is valid.
```

For this reason, I suppose, I'll have to use another function which will wrap around my `__init__` function like this:

```
def mvgc_wrapper(lll, keys, vals):
    if len(keys) != len(vals):
        raise ValueError("keys and vals must have the same length.")
    return MyVeryGenericClass(*lll, **dict(zip(keys, vals)))
```

The question is: Should my wrapper function, be a method of my class or not and for which reason and if it is the case, then how?

- On one side, except for special methods like `__new__` and `__init__`, the class instance should already exist which is not the case.
- On the other side, it would be more logical to have my wrapper be part of my class to make it monolithic.
- Or else, should I possibly define it the same way a `__new__`, with a cls parameter instead of self. I tried to make write it like this but it doesn't seem to work.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding: UTF-8

import traceback

class MyVeryGenericClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.args)+repr(self.kwargs)

    def wrapper(cls, lll, keys, vals):
        if len(keys) != len(vals):
            raise ValueError("keys and vals must have the same length.")
        return MyVeryGenericClass(*lll, **dict(zip(keys, vals)))

    def wrapper2(cls, lll, keys, vals):
        if len(keys) != len(vals):
            raise ValueError("keys and vals must have the same length.")
        return cls(*lll, **dict(zip(keys, vals)))

    def wrapper3(cls, lll, keys, vals):
        if len(keys) != len(vals):
            raise ValueError("keys and vals must have the same length.")
        return cls.MyVeryGenericClass(*lll, **dict(zip(keys, vals)))


genlist = [1, 2, 3]
genkeys = ["spam", "eggs"]
genvals = ["foo", "bar"]

try:
    cmd="instance1 = MyVeryGenericClass(genlist, genkeys, genvals)"
    print(">", cmd)
    exec(cmd)
    print("instance1 = {}".format(repr(instance1)))
except TypeError: traceback.print_exc()
print()
try:
    cmd="instance2 = instance1.wrapper(genlist, genkeys, genvals)"
    print(">", cmd)
    exec(cmd)
    print("instance2 = {}".format(repr(instance2)))
except TypeError: traceback.print_exc()
print()
try:
    cmd="failed_instance = MyVeryGenericClass.wrapper(genlist, genkeys, genvals)"
    print(">", cmd)
    exec(cmd)
    print("failed_instance = {}".format(repr(failed_instance)))
except TypeError: traceback.print_exc()
print()
try:
    cmd="failed_instance = MyVeryGenericClass.wrapper2(genlist, genkeys, genvals)"
    print(">", cmd)
    exec(cmd)
    print("failed_instance = {}".format(repr(failed_instance)))
except TypeError: traceback.print_exc()
print()
try:
    cmd="failed_instance = MyVeryGenericClass.wrapper3(genlist, genkeys, genvals)"
    print(">", cmd)
    exec(cmd)
    print("failed_instance = {}".format(repr(failed_instance)))
except TypeError: traceback.print_exc()
```

Produces:

```
RESTART: /media/raid/ArcFolder/Mes documents/Mes Textes/Mes programmes/python/init_wrapper.py
> instance1 = MyVeryGenericClass(genlist, genkeys, genvals)
instance1 = ([1, 2, 3], ['spam', 'eggs'], ['foo', 'bar']){}

> instance2 = instance1.wrapper(genlist, genkeys, genvals)
instance2 = (1, 2, 3){'eggs': 'bar', 'spam': 'foo'}

> failed_instance = MyVeryGenericClass.wrapper(genlist, genkeys, genvals)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/raid/ArcFolder/Mes documents/Mes Textes/Mes programmes/python/init_wrapper.py", line 51, in <module>
    exec(cmd)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vals'

> failed_instance = MyVeryGenericClass.wrapper2(genlist, genkeys, genvals)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/raid/ArcFolder/Mes documents/Mes Textes/Mes programmes/python/init_wrapper.py", line 58, in <module>
    exec(cmd)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: wrapper2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vals'

> failed_instance = MyVeryGenericClass.wrapper3(genlist, genkeys, genvals)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/raid/ArcFolder/Mes documents/Mes Textes/Mes programmes/python/init_wrapper.py", line 65, in <module>
    exec(cmd)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: wrapper3() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vals'
```

---

Edit : 
Thanks to @kindall, there is solution by adding `#classmethod` above the alternate constructor. But now the problem is : How do I make the difference between an alternate constructor and an alternate initializor ?

Comment: Alternate constructors typically use `@classmethod`.

Comment: thats not an interface btw, and I don't see why you wouldn't pass the 3 lists to the constructor instead of doing that

Comment: Because, my __init__ method is not able to detect the difference between both the inputs and will product the wrong result (See the difference between the content of instance1 and instance2 in my last exemple) (About interface, that's the reason why I quoted it.)

Comment: So you don't have control over the code of the class and you need to add something in between to modify the arguments on the fly?

Comment: I have control on the code of the class, but I don't wan't to loose my normal initializer.

Comment: @Kindall : Thanks to you info, I have been able to make my code run. But now, the problem, is how do I tell python that the method I'm writing is an alternative to `__new__` or to `__init__` ?

Comment: You call it directly, i.e. `MyVeryGenericClass.alternativeConstructor()`

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the class code, then you can simply do this:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, args, keys, values):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = dict(zip(keys, values))

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.args) + repr(self.kwargs)
```

Which you can use as you showed:

```py
>>> genlist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> genkeys = ["spam", "eggs"]
>>> genvals = ["foo", "bar"]
>>> a = A(genlist, genkeys, genvals)
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3]{'spam': 'foo', 'eggs': 'bar'}
```

Unless there is a good reason not to, the best thing probably is to pass directly your key/value pairs directly as keyword arguments:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

a = A(genlist, **dict(zip(genkeys, genvals)))
```

Comment: But then, I do not have my main initializer anymore.

Comment: If you don't use it for anything else then there is no point in having it, maybe you should detail what you need to have in the end (your actual goal).

Comment: It's not that I don't use it for anything else. It's just that I made the example as short as possible. My main use is to be able to call it with *arg and **kwargs, (I want to make a generic module which will be used in many different cases, so there is no point detailing cases I don't know yet). The point is that for using in a generator, it's easier to pass the 3 lists instead of a variable parameters paradigm.

Comment: I believe you forgot the «*» before genlist. by the way, you last edition is what I was doing first, but It came to the conclusion that this other way of building my object was generic enough to have it's place in my class module, and that why I wondered how this should be done.

Comment: Oh, by the way, looking at my code reminded my why the alternate constructor was needed : It's because zip won't raise an error if genkeys and genvals are not the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, Thanks to @kindall. I needed to add `@classmethod` above my alternate initializers :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding: UTF-8

import traceback

class MyVeryGenericClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.args)+repr(self.kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def wrapper(cls, lll, keys, vals):
        if len(keys) != len(vals):
            raise ValueError("keys and vals must have the same length.")
        return MyVeryGenericClass(*lll, **dict(zip(keys, vals)))

    @classmethod
    def wrapper2(cls, lll, keys, vals):
        if len(keys) != len(vals):
            raise ValueError("keys and vals must have the same length.")
        return cls(*lll, **dict(zip(keys, vals)))


genlist = [1, 2, 3]
genkeys = ["spam", "eggs"]
genvals = ["foo", "bar"]

try:
    cmd="instance1 = MyVeryGenericClass(genlist, genkeys, genvals)"
    print(">", cmd)
    exec(cmd)
    print("instance1 = {}".format(repr(instance1)))
except TypeError: traceback.print_exc()
print()
try:
    cmd="instance2 = instance1.wrapper(genlist, genkeys, genvals)"
    print(">", cmd)
    exec(cmd)
    print("instance2 = {}".format(repr(instance2)))
except TypeError: traceback.print_exc()
print()
try:
    cmd="failed_instance = MyVeryGenericClass.wrapper(genlist, genkeys, genvals)"
    print(">", cmd)
    exec(cmd)
    print("failed_instance = {}".format(repr(failed_instance)))
except TypeError: traceback.print_exc()
print()
try:
    cmd="failed_instance = MyVeryGenericClass.wrapper2(genlist, genkeys, genvals)"
    print(">", cmd)
    exec(cmd)
    print("failed_instance = {}".format(repr(failed_instance)))
except TypeError: traceback.print_exc()
```

Produces:

```
 RESTART: /media/raid/ArcFolder/Mes documents/Mes Textes/Mes programmes/python/init_wrapper.py 
> instance1 = MyVeryGenericClass(genlist, genkeys, genvals)
instance1 = ([1, 2, 3], ['spam', 'eggs'], ['foo', 'bar']){}

> instance2 = instance1.wrapper(genlist, genkeys, genvals)
instance2 = (1, 2, 3){'spam': 'foo', 'eggs': 'bar'}

> instance3 = MyVeryGenericClass.wrapper(genlist, genkeys, genvals)
instance3 = (1, 2, 3){'spam': 'foo', 'eggs': 'bar'}

> instance4 = MyVeryGenericClass.wrapper2(genlist, genkeys, genvals)
instance4 = (1, 2, 3){'spam': 'foo', 'eggs': 'bar'}
```